# how to obtain a list of domains registered in some country

Tags: php, dns, tcp, tld

I need to get a list of all domains registered in a specific country (.to in my case). How can this be done?

Something usable from PHP would be even better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains , extract the information from here, and make it as PPH array should be good enough ?

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Tonga's registry (http://www.tonic.to/) and ask really nicely.

But according to their FAQ:

> **Does Tonic offer a whois service ?**
>
> Tonic does not maintain a whois database that provides registrant information, as many of our customers consider the public display of this information invasive of their privacy. In fact, we will never sell a mailing list of our customers.

So I'm going to say you're all out of luck.